# Only catching the first occurrence of a regex string

Tags: java, regex

Currently, I am trying to catch the first occurrence of a 'space' or '->' on each line. However, my expression catches all occurrences of delimiters.

```
String delimiters = "(->)|[\\s]+"
String[] splittedLine = planArray[i].split(delimiters)
```

where `planArray[i]` is the string we're trying to split with regex, e.g. 
`leftClick 100 100`

I want leftClick to be `splittedLine[0]` and `100 100` to be `splittedLine[1]`.

Thanks

Comment: I think the parentheses and brackets are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [version of `split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) that has a `limit` parameter and limit the result to 2 parts:

```
String line = "leftClick 100 100";
String delimiters = "(->)|[\\s]+";
String[] splittedLine = line.split(delimiters, 2);      
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splittedLine));
// [leftClick, 100 100]
```

(Also, you could simplify the regex to `"->|\\s+"`.)